# Trying to authenticate google cloud platform (GCP) to use speech to text APi

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text

I am trying to use the google cloud platform (GCP) for the speech to text API in python but for some reason I can't seem to get access to the GCP to use the API. How do I authenticate my credentials?

I have tried to follow the instructions provided by google to authenticate my credentials but I am just so lost as nothing seems to be working.

I have created a GCP project, set-up billing information, enabled API and created service account without any problems.

I have tried to set my environment using command line to `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=[PATH]`

and then run the following code which has been taken straight from the google tutorial page:

```
def transcribe_streaming(stream_file):
    """Streams transcription of the given audio file."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    with io.open(stream_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
        content = audio_file.read()

    # In practice, stream should be a generator yielding chunks of audio data.
    stream = [content]
    requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=chunk)
                for chunk in stream)

    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US')
    streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(config=config)

    # streaming_recognize returns a generator.
    responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)

    for response in responses:
        # Once the transcription has settled, the first result will contain the
        # is_final result. The other results will be for subsequent portions of
        # the audio.
        for result in response.results:
            print('Finished: {}'.format(result.is_final))
            print('Stability: {}'.format(result.stability))
            alternatives = result.alternatives
            # The alternatives are ordered from most likely to least.
            for alternative in alternatives:
                print('Confidence: {}'.format(alternative.confidence))
                print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
```

I get the following error message:

```
DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

Comment: Double check your set command for errors. Double check that the variable actually points to a service account. Execute `type %GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS%`. The output should start with `"type": "service_account"`

Answer (score 1):

You can also set credentials directly in your script

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/path/to/your/crendentials.json")
client = speech.SpeechClient(credentials=credentials)
```